# How can I use max to compare Dioxus' use_state?

Tags: rust, dioxus

I'm currently using [Dioxus](https://dioxuslabs.com/) to generate a page that dynamically changes an image carousel.

What I want to achieve right now is to use the `max` function to compare the result of `use_state` to prevent the number from coming lower from 1.

Here's a simple app:

```rust
use dioxus::{events::*, hooks::UseState, prelude::*};
use log::{info, LevelFilter};
use std::cmp::{max, Ordering};

 impl PartialOrd for UseState<i32> {
     fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
         Some(self.cmp(other))
     }
 }

 impl Ord for UseState<i32> {
     fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
         self.x.cmp(&other.x)
     }
 }

/**
 * Specify <link data-trunk rel="copy-dir" href="src/assets" />
 * in the index.html to copy the files!!
 *
 * You'll see them in the dist directory!
 */

fn main() {
    dioxus_logger::init(LevelFilter::Info).expect("failed to init logger");
    dioxus::web::launch(app);
}

fn app(cx: Scope) -> Element {
    let mut index = use_state(&cx, || 1);
    let val = index.get() as &i32;
    let num = 1 as i32;
    let change_evt = move |evt: KeyboardEvent| match evt.key.as_str() {
        "ArrowRight" => index += 1,
        "ArrowLeft" => index = max(&num.try_into(), &val.try_into()),
        _ => {}
    };

    let url = format!("/assets/manga/one_piece/1042/0{}.jpg", index);
    cx.render(rsx!(img {
            src: "{url}",
        }
        div {
            class: "display",
            onkeydown: change_evt,
            button {
                class: "but",
                onclick: move |evt| {
                    println!("{evt:?}");
                    info!("{evt:?}");
                },
                "Press me!"
            },
        },
    ))
}
```

I thought at the beginning that using `index.get()` would yield me the `i32` needed to compare with `max()`.

But it complained and told me I needed to implement `PartialOrd` for `UseState{Integer}`.

I'm currently stuck trying to implement it.

Here's my `cargo.toml`

```ini
[package]
name = "rust-manga"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
dioxus = { version = "0.2.4", features = ["web", "html"] }
dioxus-html = "0.2.1"
dioxus-logger = "0.3.0"
log = "0.4.17"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When implementing a trait for something (such as `impl PartialOrd for UseState`), then at least one of the two components must belong to the crate where the `impl` is defined. But both `PartialOrd` and `UseState` are defined outside your crate, so you cannot do that.

There are two options:

1. A new type that belongs to your crate, so that you can implement traits on that:

```rust
struct MyUseState<T: 'static>(UseState<T>);

impl<T> PartialOrd for MyUseState<T> {
  fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
    todo!();
  }
}
```

The downside is that you would need to wrap instances of where you use `dioxus::hooks::UseState` in your custom type, at least whenever you want to compare things.

2. Use the methods provided by `UseState`:

If `UseState` doesn't implement the traits necessary to pass it to `std::cmp::max`, we have to get the inner value. It does offer multiple ways to do that, such as `UseState::get()`, `UseState::current()` or an implementation of `Deref`.

So we could do `max(num, *index.get())`, where `.get()` gets a `&i32`, and we derefence that to get the value. Or `max(num, **index)`, using `Deref`.

However, we still can't assign that to `index`, as an `i32` can't be assigned to an `UseState`.

That's what `UseState::modify()` is for. It allows you to modify the value in place:

```rust
// Again, `.modify()` only gives a reference to the closure, which we have to derefence.
index.modify(|val| max(num, *val))
```

Comment: Wow, Lucas, thank you so much   for explaining both concepts and why my approach was wrong. Thanks for letting me know about the second approach. Just tested it out, and worked wonders!